# Crash on custom UIButton tap event

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

There's a subclass of `UIButton`

```
@objc class OpenCloseButton: UIButton {

    /* used NSNumber due to "-swift.h" collaboration file do not generate primitive types. 
    Hence, cannot use `Bool` */

    var isOpen: Bool = 0 
}
```

Now, I put `UIButton` in storyboard and change it's class to `OpenCloseButton` and connected the following action to that button:

```
@IBAction func openCloseDetails(_ button: OpenCloseButton) {

    if button.isOpen == false { // here it crashes

        button.isOpen = true
        self.closeDetails()

    } else {

        button.isOpen = false
        self.openDetails()
    }
}
```

When App runs, it crashes when I tap on that button with

`Threas: 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x06549gfr)`

Exception break point shows the crash on second line of the method.

What am I missing here?

**Additional Info:**

Console has the following output at the crash line:

`(lldb) po button`

`▿ Optional<OpenCloseButton>`

`(lldb) po button!`

`<UIButton: 0x146059c0; frame = (728 12; 32 32); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1469ca40>>`

Comment: Cross check in storyboard. Did you added OpenCloseButton for class name for button under Custom class? If yes then print button before crash call.

Comment: Has your `OpenCloseButton` any initializer in there class?

Comment: You can use `bool` in cooperation with Obj-C, but not the `Bool?` (optional bool)

Comment: @Lalit double checked it. It is there as you've mentioned.

Comment: @zero3nna No it has not any initializers. But, I think that would not matter. Let me know, if I am wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the type of button and the value of isOpen at runtime, before entering the if-case but in the method?

Comment: @sweta.me I'm doing it, but don't trust me, trust Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35 Find a `Jukebox` class. It has `isCurrentlyPlaying` bool property. Hence, it would work

Comment: I run that code and it is working. I think you have some other reference. May be initialization issue. Please edit you question with all OpenCloseButton references.

Comment: @sweta.me  Try to remove the button action connection and then reconnect it.

Comment: @NiravD Did it. Wouldn't work :(

Comment: @Lalit OpenCloseButton has not been anywhere other than this.

Comment: @MichałZygar I got your point, used `Bool` in swift wothout `?` or `!` and it got generated in `-swift.h` file. Thank You. But the crash is there as it is. Any help?

Comment: from the debugger output it looks like the `button` is optional, while it should be a concrete object. Probably that's what casues the issue (getting property of not unwrapped optional). No idea why it happened though.

Comment: @MichałZygar It is `IBOutlet` and that's why it's set as optional. Let me edit the question with your suggested change.

Comment: So you have name conflict `@IBOutlet var button:OpenCloseButton!` and param `button:OpenCloseButton`. It the Outlet connected? You can also try renaming the param (lets say to `btn` and use `if btn.isOpen` for test purposes)

Comment: @MichałZygar Name conflict is not an issue here. `btnDetails` is name of outlet.

Comment: Got it resolved. In storyboard, somehow the `module` under the `class` was set to `none` I don't know how, but correcting it to current project got it working fine. Thank You All for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Could you add this before calling `if button.isOpen?.boolValue...`:

```
guard let button = button as? OpenCloseButton else {
    return
}
```

its just for test purpose. Does it continue to run or does it call the return in the method?

Comment: It didn't call return method. Crashed on the next line itself.

Comment: Got it resolved. In storyboard, somehow the `module` under the `class` was set to `none` I don't know how, but correcting it to current project got it working fine. Thank You for your efforts.